# Is it correct to say "our plan to go public" vs "to be out for public"?

Tags: phrases, idioms

I am writing an email about my team's plan. We were working internally (within the company) and now we are in the progress to provide our services externally.

My question is which is correct?

> "our plan to go public"

or

> "our plan to be out for public"?

Thanks

Comment: Have you ever seen "be out for public" used anywhere?

Answer (score 2):

- Our plan to make our services available to the public is ready.
- Our plan to make our services available to the market is ready.
- Our plan to sell our services to the public is ready.

Three options.

There are many ways to say it except "go public" since that means to list a company's stock on a stock exchange or reveal things that have been kept private or a secret.

[to be out for public is not idiomatic, and is close to another idiom: to be out in public. "I never go out in public without shoes."]

Comment: I have upvoted your answer. It is clearly correct. Your three options do have a slight difference in meaning, which I doubt this OP will catch. You might want to distinguish between merely making available and actively marketing.

Answer (score 1):

***To go public*** is definitely right. [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/go-public-with) defines it as

> to make something known that was secret before:
>
> - We will not ***go public*** with the results until tomorrow.

[OxfordL's](https://www.google.com/search?q=go%20public%20meaning&sxsrf=ALiCzsYCwyfeVgFh_6Ne8oxPHfMDj1LVng%3A1659025179397&ei=G7fiYqTpF4_SgQbY97uIAw&oq=go%20public&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYADIECCMQJzIFCAAQkQIyBAgAEEMyBQgAEIAEMgUILhCABDIFCAAQkQIyBAgAEEMyBQgAEIAEMgoIABCABBCHAhAUMgUIABCABDoKCAAQsQMQgwEQQzoQCC4QsQMQgwEQxwEQ0QMQQzoECC4QQzoRCC4QgAQQsQMQgwEQxwEQ0QM6EwguEIAEELEDEIMBEMcBENEDEAo6DQguELEDEIMBENQCEEM6DQguEIAEEMcBENEDEAo6BwgAEIAEEApKBAhBGABKBAhGGABQAFjuDmCPGWgAcAF4AIABfogBkwaSAQM3LjKYAQCgAQHAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz) definition is also helpful

> become a public company
>
> - The company's share price has nearly quadrupled since it ***went public***.

*To be out for public* sounds clumsy and [unidiomatic](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=go%20public%2C%20out%20for%20public&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgo%20public%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cout%20for%20public%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Yes, *go public* is OK so far as the **form** is concerned, but it requires some context to convey the **meaning** that the OP has in mind. Going public can mean offering one's services to the public, but its can also mean making something known to the public, or making one's company public (i.e. offering its stock on the stock market). This last meaning, which appears in the second example of the answer is something very different from what the question seems to be about.

Comment: In U.S business parlance, “go public” (not followed by “with”) has a specific meaning, namely to change a company to one the shares of which are publicly traded on a stock exchange. I am afraid that I must downvote this answer.